# How to convert a double to double array?

Tags: arrays, double

When I do this code, it tells me:

```
"incompatible: double cannot be converted to double[]"
```

What do I do to fix it?

```
public class Gravity
{
   public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass)
   {
      // The formula to calculate gravity is: g = (G*M)/r^2
      for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
      {
         return 6.67E-17 * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2); //incompatible error
      }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      // Initialize variables
      string[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
      double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
      double [] masses = {3.30E23, 4.87E24, 5.97E24, 6.42E23, 1.90E27, 5.68E26, 8.68E25, 1.02E26, 1.27E22}; 

      // Processing
      double[] gravities = calcGravity(radii, masses);

      // Output
      printResults(names, radii, masses, gravities);
      printToFile(gravities);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little messed up. First, to fix your code, you could make the method return a `double` instead of a `double array`.

Second, your code does not make much sense. You have a `for loop` iterating from 0 to 8, but you return from it in the very first iteration. What's the iteration for?

Comment: Well there is more to the assignment, but I didn't want you to feel like you were doing my homework for me. Should I add it?

Comment: You need to build an array of gravities in the loop, and then return the array after the loop, not return the first value.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not fresh on Java by any measure, but your compiler error is telling you exactly what it sounds like.  You're attempting to convert a double to a double array.

Looking at your function, calcGravity, you're returning a result of:

6.67E-17 * mass[i] / Math.pow(radius[i], 2);

Now, the problem is this.  You're using a return statement in a for loop, which will return a single double value.

I suppose what you're intending to do is make this calculating for each of the 9 calculations you're trying to make in calcGravity.  Therefore, what you need to do is create an array of whatever size you need, run through your for loop and set each value, and then return the array, not the individual calculation values.

```
public static double[] calcGravity(double[] radius, double[] mass)
{
    // The formula to calculate gravity is: g = (G*M)/r^2
    double[] array = new double[9]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        array[i] =  6.67E-17 * mass[i]/ Math.pow(radius[i],2);              //incompatible error
    }

    return array;
}
```

Not sure if that's  valid Java syntax for creating an array, but I think you get the point.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed my problem :)

Comment: Mark the solution then, if you would, so the topic can be closed :-)

Answer (score 0):

A function can only return only one value in a single call.
Once it returns a value, the control goes back to the calling function. However in your code you are attempting to return more than one values i.e, the value of gravity after each iteration. i suggest you modify your function as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
// Initialize variables
String[] names = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
double[] radii = {2439.7, 6051.9, 6378, 3402.5, 71492, 60270, 25562, 24774, 1195};
double [] masses = {3.30E23, 4.87E24, 5.97E24, 6.42E23, 1.90E27, 5.68E26, 8.68E25, 1.02E26, 1.27E22}; 
double gravities[]=new Double[9];
for(int i=0, i<9; i++)
{
   gravities[i] = calcGravity(radii[i] , masses[i] );
}
}
public static double calcGravity(double radius, double mass)
{
// The formula to calculate gravity is: g = (G*M)/r^2

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    return 6.67E-17 * mass/ Math.pow(radius,2);             
}
}//end of calcGravity
```

Also you had forgotten to close the calcGravity function.

Comment: Thank you for your help!